# How to show progress bar progress with specific value from ruby variable in rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I want to show progress of "cnt" for active tickets count.. cnt and cnt_close are my ruby variables. I wnat to access them in script and according to those shows my process of project.

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.loaded = true;

 min: 1
 max: 100
 var progress = setInterval(function() {
  var $bar = $('.bar');

  if ($bar.width()==200) {
      clearInterval(progress);
      $('.progress').removeClass('active');
  } else {
      $bar.width($bar.width()+1);
  }
   $bar.text($bar.width() + "%");
  }, cnt/cnt_close);
</script>
```

this is what I am working with so I want to count all active tickets in "cnt" variable according to "cnt/cnt_close" my progressbar shows me progress...

```
<% @projects.each do |p| %>
<% cnt = 0 %>
<% cnt_close = 0 %>
 <div class="span3">
 <div class="box">
  <div class="box-body box-body-nopadding">    
    <b style="color: red"><%= p.title %><br /></b>
      <% p.tickets.each do |t| %>
        <% if p.id == t.project_id %>
          <% if t.status == "New" %>
            <% cnt = cnt + 1 %>
          <% elsif t.status == "Closed" %>
            <% cnt_close += 1 %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

    Overall progress in project :
    <div class="container">
      <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 5%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="pull-left">
        Active : <%= cnt %> <br />
      </div>

    <div class="pull-right">
      Close Tickets : <%= cnt_close %> <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```